# "XYZ mentioned in newspaper ABC!" in Japanese?

Tags: translation

My organization XYZ has been mentioned in a newspaper, and I would like to post a link to the online article, together with a short explanation like "XYZ mentioned in newspaper ABC!"

How about `日本経済新聞にXYZ記載！` or `日本経済新聞にXYZの名が出る！`

What is the most natural way to say this?
I don't want to appear excessively boastful either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

記載 means to write down, and cannot be used here. 名が出る means identity exposed or revealed, and cannot be used either. 掲載される or 載る would fit in this context.

Comment: Thanks! I will use `日本経済新聞にXYZが載ってる！`

Comment: That is perfect.